# PHP Arrays - jQuery referencing issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following php:

```
1) echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Invalid Login Details: '.$user));
```

I also have the following:

```
2) $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo(json_encode($row));
```

Now consider the following jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "get_login.php",
           data: {username: getusername, password:getpassword, usertype:getusertype},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data) {
              $("#message_ajax").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.message +"</div>");
           }
        })
```

This succeeds for (1) but not for (2). This is obviously because jQuery expects a php response containing a message variable. (2) does not conform to this...I don;t know how to make this work as I am using different methods for creating the arrays...

How can I make $row in the php compatible with the data.message in the jQuery?

Comment: `echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Invalid Login Details: '$user));` is wrong, near `$user` because it will display a php fatal error

Comment: @Dogbert - $row contains a tuple from a relation (i.e. user details - fName, lName, e-mail...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$data = array();
$data["message"] = "Valid request";
$data["row"] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo(json_encode($data));
```

message = row:

```
$data = array();
$data["message"] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo(json_encode($data));
```

or two line solution (inspired by val):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo(json_encode(array("message" => $row)));
```

Comment: great, so this works...but it displays [Object object] -> how do I get it to display the actual string values?

Comment: `data.message` will be an object. If you want to display the contents, you have to iterate over its properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo(json_encode(array('message'=>'I am the message','result'=>$row));
```

Then to answer your second question on the comments something similar to this could show the information ....

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "get_login.php",
           data: {username: getusername, password:getpassword, usertype:getusertype},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data) {
              $("#message_ajax").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.message +"</div>");
              var html = '';
              for(var i = 0; i<data.result.length;i++){
                 html +='<div>'+data.result[i].fname+'</div>';
               }
              $('#result').html(html);
           }
        })
```

ofcourse you need to edit it abit where applicable .

Answer (score 0):

i believe you don't have `$row['message']` from `mysql_fetch_assoc`.
you have to explicitely define the `message` key on the array before `json_encode`.

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $row['message'] = 'Hello '.$row['username'];
    echo(json_encode($row));
```